# Find an integer solution satisfying the following equality

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Find the integer $k$ that satisfies the equality
> $$
> \frac{1}{6 \choose k} - \frac{1}{7 \choose k} = \frac{16}{3 {8 \choose k}}
> $$

Attempt: My first thought was to directly plug in the definition for $n \choose k$ into the equation. But I ended up with a polynomial $2k^2 -33k + 112 = 0$, which does not give integer root. I've check with some friends, who got the same answer. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Suggest you include in question the steps you took to arrive at your quadratic equation. Because if you include no work the question may get closed.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2FC%286%2Ck%29+-+1%2FC%287%2Ck%29+%3D+16%2F%283*C%288%2Ck%29%29) seems to agree this does not have integer solutions

Comment: I see, thanks for confirming. Was about to go insane. @gt6989b

Comment: Did you make a typo somewhere?

Comment: Similar equations such as $\frac1{\binom6k} - \frac1{\binom7k} = \frac8{3\binom8k}$ or $\frac1{\binom6k} + \frac1{\binom7k} = \frac{16}{5\binom8k}$ do have integer solutions ($k=5$ and $k=2$ in these two examples, respectively).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel No. This question was directly taken from a textbook. The book: Introduction to probability models and applications by N.Balakrishnan, Markos V. Koutras, Konstadinos G. Politis. Chapter 2.3, question 14.

Comment: May be a typo : $20$ instead of $16$ gives $k=5$